# Botframework intermittence HTTP status code GatewayTimeout

Tags: azure, timeout, botframework, chatbot

we have a botframework chatbot connected to the azure botchannel, but we have noticed that not always, but from time to time it sends us a message of `There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout`

And we have tried to verify if it is an error in the botframework, but everything seems normal and sometimes when restarting the appservice the timeout message does not appear again until the next day, and the temporary solution is to restart the appservice. The Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure nuget has already been updated to a more stable version 4.10, the appservice maintains good performance, and the GatewayTimeout we have verified that it is not for consuming any third-party service, since this message occurs even if the user only sends a greeting, for which we have not yet identified why the GatewayTimeout message is giving us, if any of you have managed to identify any fault or extra configuration to do in azure I would be very grateful.

Logs:

```
Event time  9/3/2020, 7:02:30 AM (Local time)   
Message POST to bch-mybotprd--el timed out after 15s    
Exception type  Microsoft.Bot.Schema.BotTimeoutException    
Failed method   Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__35.MoveNext

Activity ID I4sIs79vdjC9ODJNp0BDkj-m|0000003    
Status Code GatewayTimeout  
Channel ID  directline  
From ID 3fc494e2-5c52-4be9-a9f1-d70894997887    

Microsoft.Bot.Schema.BotTimeoutException:
       at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__35.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\ChannelSDK\Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector\API\BotAPI.csMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 473)
```

Comment: Does this still happen for you?

Comment: On which channel are you getting this error? Also, have you tried to locally debug your bot by making use of [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/)?